# External Accessory Framework bluetooth pair. connectedAccessories every time count 0

Tags: ios, macos, bluetooth, external-accessory

I want try read/write data with bluetooth

I try pairs:

Mac Book <-> iPod 4

custom device <-> iPod 4

I try this Apple sample (EADemo) https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/EADemo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010079

I created pair in the settings->bluetooth:

Mac Book <-> iPod 4 - ok (connected)

custom device <-> iPod 4 - ok (connected)

But

```
[[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager] connectedAccessories]
```

always get array with count 0.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The EADemo is using the External Accessory framework and therefore needs a protocol string added into the info.plist of your project. This is what apple use to lock down connections to non MFi accessories.
For more info check out the [MFi program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/)